# How to pass route variable bettwen Angular components

Tags: angular

My Angular components hierarchy look as this

```
<div class="container">
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <main>
    <app-title></app-title>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

And I want to setup some variables in <app-title>, for example

```
 <h1>{{PageTitle}}</h1>
```

From components <router-outlet>, for example from <app-referrals> components, http://localhost:4200/referrals on order to

```
PageTitle = "This is referalls page"
```

What correct way to do this simple task with Angular 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the router outlet event `activate` like below.

**App HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <main>
    <app-title [PageTitle]="MyTitle" ></app-title>
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

**App TS**

```
MyTitle:string = "my default title";
onActivate(component){
  if(component.PageTitle){
    this.MyTitle = PageTitle;
  }
}
```

Of course, you should set a `@Input() PageTitle` in your app-title component and make sure all your routed components has a `PageTitle` property. You can strict it by implementing interface or extending a base class with `PageTitle` property.

Answer (score 0):

you have to setup an observable on title and subscribe it in title component and change this title on referrals component for example.